# BODMAS Rule for simple calculations

Tags: arithmetic

I was helping my little sister solve a sixth grade math problem which went something like this -

Z = 4 + 3 - 3 + 2
What is the final value of Z ?

In this case , my brain directly jumped to the BODMAS and I did the addition part first. I thus got -

(4+3) - (3+2) = 7 - 5 = 2

I got to know that this answer was WRONG and I had to just follow it through without considering the BODMAS. And the answer would be something like this -

Z = 4 + 3 - 3 + 2
  = 7 - 3 + 2
  = 4 + 2
  = 6

Which obviously gives 6.

This confused me. Is BODMAS a conditional rule ?? When is it used then ? ( Btw it is quite kiddish but I have the doubt anyways )

For example I checked on the net and I got something like this,

To calculate == 5 + 3 * 2
We use the BODMAS here,
             == 5 + 6 = 11.

Well if I would have just followed it through here I would get 16.

Any clarification about the BODMAS idea please ?? There is clearly a HUGE misconception.

(For god's sake don't downvote my question, please answer if you can)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You have done the wrong bracketing in your first calculation i.e., $4+3-3+2 \ne (4+3)-(3+2)$. Rather, $4+3-3+2 = (4+3)-(3-2)$. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you have an expression like
$$
Z = 4+3-3+2
$$
you cannot just arbitrarily add parentheses around the terms - or if you do so, you must be very careful! When you changed it to
$$
Z = (4+3)-(3+2)
$$
you have already made a mistake and changed the value of the expression. Why? Because you have flipped the sign of the last $+2$. Now it's actually $-2$ due to the minus-sign in front of the parentheses. So don't do this.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. With your example of $5 + 3 * 2$, note that multiplication has a higher priority than addition. In BODMAS, as shown in [BODMAS - What does BODMAS stand for? The Free Dictionary](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/BODMAS), the priorities are Brackets Order, Division & Multiply, then Add & Subtract. Thus, you do the multiplication before the addition, which is why you get $5 + 6 = 11$, as you noted. In particular, you don't do the addition first, then multiplying, as you indicated where you would then get $(5 + 3) * 2 = 8 * 2 = 16$.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who took the time here. It is very clear now what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compute $4+3-3+2$, since you only have additions and subtrations (which have the same priority level) and there are no parenthesis, you just do\begin{align}\overbrace{4+3}^{\phantom7=7}-3+2&=\overbrace{7-3}^{\phantom4=4}+2\\&=4+2\\&=6.\end{align}Your mistake consisted in adding parenthesis when there were none.